# How to get grouped array of fields from DataTable with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, datarow

I have a `DataTable`

```
var tbl = new DataTable();
tbl.Columns.Add("key",typeof(int));
tbl.Columns.Add("value",typeof(int));
tbl.Rows.Add(1, 2);
tbl.Rows.Add(1, 4);
tbl.Rows.Add(3, 6);
tbl.Rows.Add(3, 8);
tbl.Rows.Add(3, 10);
```

from this table I want only `values` grouped by `key` something like

```
{{2,4},{6,8,10}}
```

more precisely `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>>`

I have designed a query

```
var res = from row in tbl.AsEnumerable() 
           group row by row.Field<int>("key") 
           into nGroup  select nGroup;
```

which gives me groups of `DataRow` combined with `key` i.e. `IEnumerable<IGrouping<int, DataRow>>`.

How do I select `value` only?

Comment: Try following : var results = tbl.AsEnumerable()
                .GroupBy(x => x.Field<int>("key"))
                .Select(x => new KeyValuePair<int, int>(x.First().Field<int>("value"), x.Last().Field<int>("value"))).ToList();

Comment: @jdweng: It partially works. As far as I understand, it takes only first and last element of each group. But groups can have unlimited number of elements (see updated answer).

Comment: Then use following : var results = tbl.AsEnumerable()
                .GroupBy(x => x.Field<int>("key"))
                .Select(x => x.Select(y => y.Field<int>("value")).ToList()).ToList();

Comment: @jdweng: Yes that works. Would you, please, make an answer (preferably with LINQ syntax). I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each `nGroup`, you need to select the `value`s:

```
var res = from row in tbl.AsEnumerable()
          group row by row.Field<int>("key") into nGroup
          select (
              from n in nGroup
              select n.Field<int>("value")
          );
```